# Span of a set to vectors which do not form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the dimension of a span of a set to vectors which do not form a basis in rn?[image]

How would be find the dimension of the span of v1 v2 and v3 if they don't form a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I've edited my answer.. if something is not clear ask :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is  $\le n$..

If the dimension were $n$, they would be a basis.

EDIT:

Now that you've added information, you can see that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are independent. This implies that (for the $\lambda$ you've found), $v_3$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, and the $\dim span(v_1, v_2, v_3) = 2$

Comment: the dimension of a subspace is the number of vectors in the basis of the subspace so in this case as v1,v2 and v3 were not forming a basis i didn't know what to do

Comment: but as you said v1 and v2 are L.I so do we can think of them forming a basis so the span of v1 v2 and v3 is 2?

Comment: V1 and v2 form a basis of the span of v1 v2 and v3